# Verbose logging for svn ssh connection

Tags: linux, svn, ssh

Does anyone one know how get SVN to log the details of the ssh connection when operating through an ssh connection?

When I can't connect svn always gives me:

```
To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
```

I've looked in the [tunnels] section of the config and nothing is currently enabled. It seems like you can specify how ssh gets called and I tried specifying a -v to ssh through this method but it seemed to have no effect. What I really want is -v output for ssh when SVN tries to connect. Although any additional logging would be good.

How do I get verbose ssh logging through SVN?

I am using SVN at the command line on linux.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using *nix like systems or cygwin on windows, you can try with this method:

```
$ export SVN_SSH="ssh -v "
$ svn checkout svn+ssh://xyz
```

Comment: Or even `SVN_SSH="ssh -v " svn ...` if you want to do this for a single command, without exporting the variable.

Comment: Both `set SVN_SSH="SSH -vvv "` and setting the ssh value in `[tunnels]` section of the config don't seem to work for me on Windows.

Answer (score -2):

I just had the same issue. As described [here](http://benjchristensen.com/2010/06/01/useless-svn-error-message-network-connection-closed-unexpectedly/), removing `~/.ssh/known_hosts` resolved it for me.

Comment: Answers that just link to an external resource bear the risk of becoming worthless once the link expires. It's preferred to summarize the actual solution inline here.

Comment: Yep, broken link